# How to query blogs posts of WordPress sub domain?

Tags: multisite, query-posts, subdomains

I am using WordPress 3.2.1 multi-user. I need to show posts from a specific sub domain in my home page, for example: http://mysite.com/sub-blog. I need to show posts from sub-blog in my home page.

Is their any special code to query from a specific blog?

Answer (score 2):

You're probably going to have to write some custom SQL for that.  Here's an example function that would do this.  It's slightly insecure as we can't use $wpdb->prepare to put the blog_id in (it surrounds anything inserted with quotes).

```
<?php
function wpse33779_get_posts_from_blog( $blog_id = 1 )
{
    // is this is the current blog, just get posts...
    if( 1 === $blog_id )
    {
        return get_posts();
    }
    else 
    {
        // make sure this is a number.
        $blog_id = absint( $blog_id );
    }

    // did absint kill our blog id?
    if( ! $blog_id ) return array();

    global $wpdb;
    $a = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * from {$wpdb->base_prefix}{$blog_id}_posts WHERE 'post' = post_type AND 'publish' = post_status" );
    $posts = $wpdb->get_results( $a );
    return $posts;
}
```

I'm not good at writing SQL, but you get the idea.  You could flesh that function out to be as full featured as `get_posts` as well.

You could also use `switch_to_blog`

```
<?php
switch_to_blog( $blod_id );
$posts = get_posts();
// do stuff with posts
restore_current_blog();
```

That said, `switch_to_blog` is probably not a great idea.  It's really slow.

Answer (score 0):

There are also two plugins you may find useful for this:

[ThreeWPBroadcast](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/threewp-broadcast/) and [WP MU Sitewide tags](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-sitewide-tags/)